# Find JAR File associate with class name

Tags: linux, bash, unix, jar, grep

Am very new to Linux scripting, my requirement is to find the jars corresponding the class files. 
I've the list of class file names in the text file, and trying to loop through each line in the text file and grepping the jars directory to find the jar associated to the class file.

```
while IFS= read -r line 
do
echo "$(grep -l `echo "$line"` \Jar\Directory\.jar)"
done < ClassFiles.txt
```

When am running this, its printing empty lines. But it returns valid results if i execute the grep statement separately in the command line.

> Jar/Directory path will contain tons of jar files.
>
> ClassFiles.txt will contain list of class file names
>   ClassName1
>   ClassName2
>   ClassName3....
>
> Script file just prints empty lines (as many empty lines as no of class files in ClassFiles.txt)

Comment: Please provide some same lines from \Jar\Direrctory\.jar and ClassFiles.txt and some sample output.    What I want to do is run your script locally and debug it, but I have to create them myself.  Are you running this on  a windows platform?  If not the \ is  the wrong path separator.  I don't know if the \ is escaping 'J', 'D', and '.'.  Try this syntax instead:  `grep -l "$line" \Jar\Directory\*.jar`  - get rid of those unnecessary `echo`s.

Comment: Thanks, Updated the question as per the ask. You can find the updated information in last few lines.. Is that giving enough information ?

Comment: I'll point out the obvious problem, the asterisk is missing in front of .jar.  I suspect that it is a formatting issue, though.  Anyway, see if you can simplify  a bit by removing echo's.

Comment: Yes, it's a formatting issue. As you suggested, tried the same without echos, but no luck ! Resulting same

Comment: First try one classfile and 1 jar. Linux slashes are like `/`. Does something work like `jar tvf /some/directory/somefile.jar` ? Please show some lines of the `jar` output and the `Classfiles.txt` file (hopefully without `\r`).